# how to update specific table inside dataset in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datatable, dataset, viewstate

i have a dataset which contains three tables dt1, dt2, and dt3 (in the sequence), now i am maintaining the viewstate for every table, to retain the table across postback, (i.e i have latest DataTable inside viewstate), now the problem is i want to apply ViewState of dt3 to the respective table in DataSet, i.e dt3, i am doing below:

```
dataSet.Tables[(it will be dynamically fetched, say for here its) 0] = ViewState["DataTable" + (it will be dynamically fetched, say for here its) 0]
```

but here i am getting error saying dataSet.Tables[] is read-only.
can any one help how shall i go about at. Let me know if anyone needs more information about my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(YourDataTable);
```

OR

```
ds.Tables.AddRange(YourDataTableArray);
```

To update an existing table in `ds` from `ViewState` you can try two approaches.

1. Remove Table from `DataSet` by using `DataSet.Tables.Remove("Table");` method, Note that you should not rely on `index` approach to fetch Tables from DataSet instead you should provide your Tables a unique name so that you can fetch and remove them when you want to.
2. You can use loop approach to fetch rows from your `ViewState DataTable` and then insert them into DataSet's Table one by one, Something like this.

---

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Clear();
DataTable dtFromViewState = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
foreach (DataRow row in dtFromViewState.Rows)
  ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
```

Comment: hi @yogi thanks for your reply, actually i want to update the existing table on a specific index in the dataset, with the above method, i will be adding new table and not updating the existing one.

Comment: i tried above ds.Tables[0], but it says ds.Tables[0] is read-only